# Hi, I don't know why these codes don't work?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to figure out whats wrong with these codes. I am learning Python from a book and it had these codes as an example for using `return` in a function. However, it doesn't seem to work. Could someone tell me why it is not working?

```
def prompt(n):
    value = int(input("Please enter integer #", n, ": ", sep=""))
    return value

print("This program adds together two integers.") 
value1 = prompt(1) # Call the function
value2 = prompt(2) # Call the function again 
sum = value1 + value2
print(value1, "+", value2, "=", sum)
```

Comment: you can't pass keyword args to `input`, you can't pass multiple args to `input`. Just use `value = int(input("Please enter integer #" + str(n) + ": "))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace

```
value = int(input("Please enter integer #", n, ": ", sep=""))
```

with

```
value = int(input("Please enter integer #" + str(n) + ": "))
```

Your book is using the `input` function incorrectly.

The `print` function accepts multiple inputs and will print them all, separated by `sep` keyword input. It appears that your book is trying to use `input` like `print`, which is incorrect.

Comment: Thank you. You are correct. I think i should find a better book.

Answer (score 0):

you can refer this [python tutorial for input](https://www.python-course.eu/input.php) document

```
def prompt(n):
    value = int(input("Please enter integer #" + str(n) + ": "))  # Error in this line
    return value

print("This program adds together two integers.") 
value1 = prompt(1) # Call the function
value2 = prompt(2) # Call the function again 
sum = value1 + value2
print(value1, "+", value2, "=", sum)
```